# How plt.pcolormesh() function work in python

Tags: python, image-processing, signals, signal-processing

I want to convert signal power into image thats why i need to know how plt.pcolormesh() function work after stft transform of signal ?

Comment: Why not just use plt.plot? Also might want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: but i want to color map of signal power. It works well but question is how does power of signal converted into color map ?

Comment: Please show us your code and what have you tried, and that way it'll be easier to help.

Comment: [link] (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html)

Answer (score 0):

@ HasanShovon the link which you provided on your comment box is actually working on STFT method or algorithm. STFT stands for "Short time Fourier transform". I have attached the link of the youtube video for it. Because I can't example virtually it will be too big. Kindly, find the link below and it is for 1 hours, please see the complete video it will clear your all doughts. Thank You.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiMge5T3d9I